# How to call a function from inside an object

Tags: javascript, function-calls

Let's suppose I have an object like this in javascript:

```
obj = {
    prop1  : 0,
    prop2  : 1,
    func1 : function (){
         var x = {
             func_Inner : function(){
                 //ATTEMPTING TO CALL FUNC2 ON obj WON'T WORK
                 this.func2()

                 //NEITHER THIS
                 this.func2().bind(obj);
             }
         }
         x.f()
         this.func2() 
    },
    func2 : function (){
         console.log(this)
         console.log(this.prop1,this.prop2)
    }
}
```

I'd like to call func2 from inside func_Inner , how could I?

Comment: Should `x.f()` be `x.func_Inner()`? I don't see an `f` function defined anywhere.

Comment: In this specific case you could simply call `obj.func2()`.

Comment: Have a look at [javascript - How does the "this" keyword work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: `obj.func2()` maybe?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the context of the function `func_Inner` which is not the obj's context.

An alternative is binding the context `this` to the function `func_Inner`

```js
var obj = {
    prop1  : 0,
    prop2  : 1,
    func1 : function (){
         var x = {
             func_Inner : function(){
                 //ATTEMPTING TO CALL FUNC2 ON obj WON'T WORK
                 this.func2()

                 //NEITHER THIS
                 //this.func2().bind(obj);
             }
         }
         // Here's is bound to the current context.
         x.func_Inner.bind(this)(); 
    },
    func2 : function (){
         //console.log(this)
         console.log(this.prop1,this.prop2)
    }
}

obj.func1();
```

Comment: Got it. That's embarrassing for me to do the bind thinggy in wrong place